# How to add multiple statements

Tags: javascript, html, input

Right now I have a form where you input and submit your age and some text will appear when the button is clicked. There is two different texts now, one for the ones under 18 years and one for over 18 years.

What I want is to make a text for 0 - 17, 18 - 25, 26 - 30 and so on. But how do I do that?

Basically a form where you get different outputs whether or not you should be smoking.

```
<input id="age" value="18" class="text-center" />
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button"> trigger </button>    

<h1 id="dontsmoke"></h1>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var age, smokeable;
        age = document.getElementById("age").value;
        smokeable = (age < 18) ? "Don't smoke" : "Still, don't smoke";
        document.getElementById("dontsmoke").innerHTML = smokeable + "...";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You will have to remove the ternary statement and use a normal `if-else`

Comment: Look into switch statements here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Answer (score 3):

Just chain your ternary operator like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var age, smokeable;
    age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    smokeable = (age < 18) ? "A" : (age > 17 && age < 26) ? "B" : (age >25 && age < 31) ? "C" : "Outside of age range";
}
```

---

**jsFiddle** with the **Ternary Operator** approach: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/3jys6fah/4/

---

Or you could use the standard `if/else` statement approach like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var age, smokeable;
    age = document.getElementById("age").value;

    if(age < 18) {
        smokeable = "A";
    }
    else if(age > 17 && age < 26) {
        smokeable = "B";
    }
    else if(age > 25 && age < 31) {
        smokeable = "C";
    }
    else {
        smokeable = "Outside of age range";
    }
}
```

---

**jsFiddle** with the standard **`if/else` statement** approach: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/3jys6fah/7/

---

Or you could use the `switch` statement approach like this:

```
var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
switch (true) {
    case (age < 18):
        smokeable = "A";
        break;
    case (age < 26):
        smokeable = "B";
        break;
    case (age < 31):
        smokeable = "C";
        break;
    default:
        smokeable = "Outside of age range";
    }
```

---

**jsFiddle** with the **`switch` statement** approach: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/3jys6fah/14/

Comment: @GarisMSuero Other than the extra 'ages' typo, I cant seem to find this bug you're talking about. There is a fiddle for each approach where you can test random ages and see if 18 returns "Outside of age range" in any of them or not.

Comment: And thanks for the update on the extra conditions in the switch example even though I kept them there as an extra emphasis on how switch works. I updated it to the shorter version regardless. Again, thanks for the heads up mate :)

Comment: I updated the extra 'ages' typo out too btw. Thanks for the heads up on that one too. Gave your answer a +1 as a token of appreciation man :) Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I saw a `> 18` on the second evaluation of each one.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, use a normal `if-else` block, I will suggest this way for readability purposes, over using multiple ternary operators

```
if (age <= 17) { 
   smokeable = "Don't smoke"; 
} else if (age >= 18 && age <=25) { 
   smokeable = "Still, don't smoke"
} else if (age >= 26 && age <=30) {
   smokeable = "Still don't smoke, but you are old enough to decide for yourself";
} else {
   smokeable = "Do whatever you want";
}
```

as @nawed-khan suggested, you can also use a switch statement

```
switch (true) {
    case (age < 18):
        smokeable = "Don't smoke";
        break;
    case (age < 26):
        smokeable = "Still, don't smoke"
        break;
    case (age < 30):
        smokeable = "Still don't smoke, but you are old enough to decide for yourself";
        break;
    default:
        smokeable = "Do whatever you want";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than multiple if/else or ternary equations - use a **switch statement** which allows for a series of conditions and resultant actions if the condition matches.

Note the use of (true) in the switch statement - this means that when the stated condition == true - do that action.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var age, smokeable;
    age = parseInt(document.getElementById("age").value);
    switch(true) {
    case age > 17 && age <= 25:
      smokeable = "Still too young to smoke";
      break;
     case age > 25 && age <=30:
      smokeable = "Smoke 'em if you got 'em";
      break;
    default:
      smokeable = "Don't smoke";
  }

   document.getElementById("dontsmoke").innerHTML = smokeable + "...";
}
```

```html
<input id="age" value="18" class="text-center" />
<button onclick="myFunction()" type="button"> trigger </button>
<h1 id="dontsmoke"></h1>
```